# How to access $route within a splitted (vuex) getters.js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I am using vuex as splitted (getters.js, mutations.js, actions.js, state.js) files and I want to use the $route plugin variable inside the splitted getters.js file. Actually I used them all-in-one before but I switched to quasar and quasar is suggesting somehow to use the vuex module in splitted files. Well it is not suggesting but it has an example there. I know I could use it the old way but I want to try this and due to my lack of knowlegde I am not sure. So it is like:

```
└── store
      └─ routes
          ├── state.js
          ├── actions.js
          ├── mutations.js
          ├── getters.js
          └── index.js
```

and in index.js they all are bound like:

```
import state from './state'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as actions from './actions'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  state
}
```

well here within the getters.js file I export const my previous used functions. But I need to access the $route plugin in one of them.

```
export const current_route = state => {
    return this.$route;
}
```

By the way I also know that I can use the this.$route directly where ever I need (whithout using the vuex getter) instead but I just want to know how to access those variables (or even if it is even possible) inside these splitted files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the source code of `vue-router`:

```js
  Vue.mixin({
    beforeCreate () {
      if (isDef(this.$options.router)) {
        /* something else */
        Vue.util.defineReactive(this, '_route', this._router.history.current)
      } else {
        this._routerRoot = (this.$parent && this.$parent._routerRoot) || this
      }
      /* something else */
    }
  })

  Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$route', {
    get () { return this._routerRoot._route }
  })
```

As you see, `$route` is the alias of `$router.history.current`.
So you can import `router` directly:

```js
import router from 'path/to/your/router'
export const current_route = state => {
  return router.history.current
}
```